# Packets are greater than configured MTU

Tags: wireshark, tcpdump

I made a tcpdump and captured packets, the configured MTU is 2140. I am analysing pcap files using Wireshark.

According to the configured MTU the expected maximum size of the packets should be 2154 (2140 bytes +14 ethernet header bytes). But I see packets of size greater than  2154 (ex 9010 bytes), On analyzing I found that these packets are generated on the machine where I made tcpdump (let's say A) and have the destination to another machine (let's say B). I expect a packet to be fragmented before it is sent to another host. I found some explanations online that says tcpdump captures packets before NIC breakdown, though this seems to be a valid explanation but it seems to contradict in my case because on machine A, I received packets of size greater than 2154 from B. Any thoughts, on why machine A is sending and receiving packets greater than configured MTU.

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing is most likely the result of TCP Segment Reassembly Offloading.  This is a feature available on some network cards with matching drivers.

The idea is that the reassembly of many of the TCP segments is handled in the NIC itself.  This turns out to be pretty effective in reducing overhead on the CPU/OS side since the network driver need only handle, perhaps, 1 "packet" out of 10, seeing just one large packet, rather than receiving and reassembling all 10.

You can read more about it [here](https://sandilands.info/sgordon/segmentation-offloading-with-wireshark-and-ethtool).

Comment: What do you expect to see on the receiving side?  the MTU-sized tcp packets that the NIC on the sender generated?

Answer (score 0):

*Updated answer*

**If your packet is UDP**

This behaviour is normal. but there is not much you can do to see the individual packets on the end machines. The UDP packet is broken down into MTU compliant packets and reassembled at the Link layer, usually by specific hardware. This is too low to to be captured by Wireshark/pcap.
If you want to capture the individual broken down packets, you have to do this on an intermediate machine/network card, for example a gateway between the two hosts, because the original UDP packet is not reassembled until it reaches its final destination. Note : this gateway can be virtual.
See [notes.shichao.io/tcpv1/ch10](http://notes.shichao.io/tcpv1/ch10)

*Leaving this here in case someone with the same problem comes...*

**If your packet is TCP :**

It sounds like Wireshark is reassembling packets for you. This is often the default for TCP streams. You can change this by richt-click on a stream -> Protocol Preferences -> Allow subdissectors to reassemble TCP.

Comment: there is no such option "Allow subdissectors to reassemble TCP", the protocol which I am receiving is UDP not tcp.

Comment: Ok, this makes sense, as TCP is reassembled in ~application layer whereas UDP is reassembled in ~link layer. You would have to sniff at a lower level to get the fragmented packets, but sadly I don't think this is possible. You could however sniff on a gateway between the two hosts, as the UDP packets are only reassembled when they reach their final destination.

Comment: Seems to be a valid explanation. I was not knowing about the reassembly of UDP at the link layer. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: can you please refer me to a link which explains about udp reassembly in link layer.

Comment: It's not Wireshark doing it.  See my answer below.